# Is there way to improve this regex code?

Tags: java, regex

I did this code in Java to take blank spaces before some chars like `>` `<` `/>` and if there is more than one space blank in the line will reduce to one.

So my code is.

```
return source.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").replaceAll("[[\\>][\\s]][[\\s][\\>]]", ">").replaceAll("[[\\<][\\s]][[\\s][\\<]]", "<").replaceAll("[\\s][/>]", "/>");
```

So can I improve my regex code?

My test code is..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"  versao="2.00" > 
<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"><infNFe Id="NFe31130821483359001109550010002217051649842350" versao="2.00"><ide><cUF>31</cUF><cNF>64984235</cNF><natOp>VENDA PROD.ESTAB.SUBST.TRIBUTA</natOp><indPag>1</indPag><mod>55</mod><serie>1</serie><nNF>221705</nNF><dEmi>2013-08-07</dEmi><dSaiEnt>2013-08-07</dSaiEnt><tpNF>1</tpNF><cMunFG>3147105</cMunFG><tpImp>2</tpImp><tpEmis>1</tpEmis><cDV>0</cDV><tpAmb>1</tpAmb><finNFe>1</finNFe><procEmi>0</procEmi><verProc>4.0.0.36</verProc></ide><emit><CNPJ>21483359001109</CNPJ><xNome>COOPERATIVA DOS GRANJEIROS DO OESTE DE MINAS LTDA</xNome><xFant>ABATEDOURO</xFant><enderEmit><xLgr>Rod RODOVIA BR 262</xLgr><nro>S/N</nro><xCpl>KM - 402</xCpl><xBairro>POVOADO GOMES</xBairro><cMun>3147105</cMun><xMun>PARA DE MINAS</xMun><UF>MG</UF><CEP>35661470</CEP><cPais>1058</cPais><xPais>Brasil</xPais><fone>03732365566</fone></enderEmit><IE>4713164920659</IE><CRT>3</CRT></emit><dest><CNPJ>07121048000105</CNPJ><xNome>SUPERMERCADO SAFRA LTDA</xNome><enderDest><xLgr>RUA TEOFILO ANDRADE</xLgr><nro>7</nro><xBairro>CENTRO</xBairro><cMun>3121407</cMun><xMun>DESTERRO DE ENTRE RIOS</xMun><UF>MG</UF><CEP>35494000</CEP><cPais>1058</cPais><xPais>Brasil</xPais><fone>3137361535</fone></enderDest><IE>2142099300090</IE></dest><det nItem="1"><prod><cProd>11007</cProd><cEAN>7898296060227</cEAN><xProd>COXA S/ COXA FRANGO CONGELADO CX. 20KG</xProd><NCM>02071400</NCM><EXTIPI>00</EXTIPI><CFOP>5401</CFOP><uCom>KG</uCom><qCom>100</qCom><vUnCom>3.7</vUnCom><vProd>370.00</vProd><cEANTrib>7898296060227</cEANTrib><uTrib>KG</uTrib><qTrib>100</qTrib><vUnTrib>3.7</vUnTrib><indTot>1</indTot><xPed>103197</xPed><nItemPed>3</nItemPed></prod><imposto><ICMS><ICMS70><orig>0</orig><CST>70</CST><modBC>3</modBC><pRedBC>61.11</pRedBC><vBC>143.89</vBC><pICMS>18.00</pICMS><vICMS>25.90</vICMS><modBCST>4</modBCST><pMVAST>15.00</pMVAST><pRedBCST>0.39</pRedBCST><vBCST>165.48</vBCST><pICMSST>18.00</pICMSST><vICMSST>3.89</vICMSST></ICMS70></ICMS><IPI><cEnq>999</cEnq><IPINT><CST>53</CST></IPINT></IPI><PIS><PISNT><CST>06</CST></PISNT></PIS><COFINS><COFINSNT><CST>06</CST></COFINSNT></COFINS></imposto><infAdProd>7898296060227 -</infAdProd></det><det nItem="2"><prod><cProd>11046</cProd><cEAN>7898296060173</cEAN><xProd>FRANGO CONGELADO CX. 20KG</xProd><NCM>02071200</NCM><EXTIPI>00</EXTIPI><CFOP>5401</CFOP><uCom>KG</uCom><qCom>200</qCom><vUnCom>3</vUnCom><vProd>600.00</vProd><cEANTrib>7898296060173</cEANTrib><uTrib>KG</uTrib><qTrib>200</qTrib><vUnTrib>3</vUnTrib><indTot>1</indTot><xPed>103197</xPed><nItemPed>1</nItemPed></prod><imposto><ICMS><ICMS70><orig>0</orig><CST>70</CST><modBC>3</modBC><pRedBC>61.11</pRedBC><vBC>233.34</vBC><pICMS>18.00</pICMS><vICMS>42.00</vICMS><modBCST>4</modBCST><pMVAST>15.00</pMVAST><pRedBCST>0.39</pRedBCST><vBCST>268.34</vBCST><pICMSST>18.00</pICMSST><vICMSST>6.30</vICMSST></ICMS70></ICMS><IPI><cEnq>999</cEnq><IPINT><CST>53</CST></IPINT></IPI><PIS><PISNT><CST>06</CST></PISNT></PIS><COFINS><COFINSNT><CST>06</CST></COFINSNT></COFINS></imposto><infAdProd>7898296060173 -</infAdProd></det><det nItem="3"><prod><cProd>11004</cProd><cEAN>7898296060203</cEAN><xProd>PEITO FRANGO CONGELADO CX. 20 KG</xProd><NCM>02071400</NCM><EXTIPI>00</EXTIPI><CFOP>5401</CFOP><uCom>KG</uCom><qCom>100</qCom><vUnCom>3.9</vUnCom><vProd>390.00</vProd><cEANTrib>7898296060203</cEANTrib><uTrib>KG</uTrib><qTrib>100</qTrib><vUnTrib>3.9</vUnTrib><indTot>1</indTot><xPed>103197</xPed><nItemPed>4</nItemPed></prod><imposto><ICMS><ICMS70><orig>0</orig><CST>70</CST><modBC>3</modBC><pRedBC>61.11</pRedBC><vBC>151.67</vBC><pICMS>18.00</pICMS><vICMS>27.30</vICMS><modBCST>4</modBCST><pMVAST>15.00</pMVAST><pRedBCST>0.39</pRedBCST><vBCST>174.42</vBCST><pICMSST>18.00</pICMSST><vICMSST>4.10</vICMSST></ICMS70></ICMS><IPI><cEnq>999</cEnq><IPINT><CST>53</CST></IPINT></IPI><PIS><PISNT><CST>06</CST></PISNT></PIS><COFINS><COFINSNT><CST>06</CST></COFINSNT></COFINS></imposto><infAdProd>7898296060203 -</infAdProd></det><total><ICMSTot><vBC>528.90</vBC><vICMS>95.20</vICMS><vBCST>608.24</vBCST><vST>14.29</vST><vProd>1360.00</vProd><vFrete>0.00</vFrete><vSeg>0.00</vSeg><vDesc>0.00</vDesc><vII>0.00</vII><vIPI>0.00</vIPI><vPIS>0.00</vPIS><vCOFINS>0.00</vCOFINS><vOutro>0.00</vOutro><vNF>1374.29</vNF></ICMSTot></total><transp><modFrete>0</modFrete><transporta><CNPJ>21483359001109</CNPJ><xNome>COOPERATIVA DOS GRANJEIROS DO OESTE DE MINAS LTDA ABATEDOURO</xNome><IE>4713164920659</IE><xEnder>Rod RODOVIA BR 262 N. S/N KM - 402</xEnder><xMun>PARA DE MINAS</xMun><UF>MG</UF></transporta><veicTransp><placa>HIH2860</placa><UF>MG</UF></veicTransp><vol><qVol>500</qVol><esp>VOLUMES</esp><pesoL>400.000</pesoL><pesoB>400.000</pesoB></vol></transp><cobr><fat><nFat>221705</nFat><vOrig>1374.29</vOrig><vLiq>1374.29</vLiq></fat><dup><nDup>000221705-01</nDup><dVenc>2013-08-28</dVenc><vDup>1374.29</vDup></dup></cobr><infAdic><infAdFisco>REDUCAO DE 61,11% CONF LETRA A1 ITEM 19 DA - PARTE 1 DO ANEXO IV RICMS 43.080/02 - E C/ COBRANCA POR ST - -</infAdFisco><infCpl>ORDEM DE CARGA: 18313</infCpl></infAdic></infNFe><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" /><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /><Reference URI="#NFe31130821483359001109550010002217051649842350"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" /></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /><DigestValue>JOjHIJzegFkL7ZfGkfAgSwP0+s4=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>Qvsom1D+sQZdrq9Y5rfMCEDBUPeRD5iToj3prhoUh0Mfy1zR0dLzTIyp56qIGsPXYogheRuR9PQVzqEc3AK5alK3tkEf+T+zYz3F/xAb7Fyo+/txye625R0D4zm23xvINlLcg0Jhs4S+OIwvDjkX6ICD/bQbP0U55mhqSW71hAYzHkRWiitmy5MJQ00YphvPBw2ikaHrFEy8cy/gYxzs3HWOHHk51AavnhQ/eqK2VcJP7NTAXeECJniz21tVE3CwzLLCRqJhm8nNAsVt8zwV0BTX0nk4osW4GtGUgQWuF5u3roHdYNfNn3MVVdV1OBr3JHHVV8RwyFpWuX6ZuQTI0g==</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><X509Data><X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature></NFe>
<protNFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="2.00"><infProt><tpAmb>1</tpAmb><verAplic>13_0_94</verAplic><chNFe>31130821483359001109550010002217051649842350</chNFe><dhRecbto>2013-08-07T01:52:47</dhRecbto><nProt>131131174998806</nProt><digVal>JOjHIJzegFkL7ZfGkfAgSwP0+s4=</digVal><cStat>100</cStat><xMotivo>Autorizado o uso da NF-e</xMotivo></infProt></protNFe>
</nfeProc>
```

Comment: This is probably better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Can you add an example string with all cases and the result you want to obtain with it.

Comment: What does `"[[\\>][\\s]][[\\s][\\>]]"` mean to you?  Why are you nesting square brackets two deep?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I put in my question the example code

Comment: @MikeSamuel mean `and` for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What bout using `"\\s+"` with replace function: `string.replaceAll("\\s+", " ")` which will remove all the white space but one.

`X+` expression is known as *Quantifiers*: which specifies `X` occur one or more times

**Edit:** in response to your comment:

The simplest approach would be to make two subsequent call of `replaceAll("\\s+>", " >")` and then `replaceAll("\\s+(/>)", " />")`;

```
String a = "asd     > bhsj       <   />   b";
a = a.replaceAll("\\s+>", " >").replaceAll("\\s+(/>)", " />");
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: Because my String need to have space with the other words, only these String above need to take off that space

Comment: updated the answer, have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt at a character class is messed up (you can't nest them like that), and you don't need to escape those characters.

This achieves what (I think) you want:

```
return source.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").replaceAll(" (?=/?>|<)", "");
```

What's going on here is first multiple whitespace chars (`\s+`) are replaced by a single space, then spaces followed by `>`, `/>` or `<` (asserted using a look-ahead) are removed (replaced by a blank).